Why is R looking for tcltk in the wrong place, and how to fix it?
R keeps giving me a message that tcltk DLL is linked to '/opt/X11/lib/libX11.6.dylib'. That's a problem because tcltk is actually in opt/R/arm64, where the R installer put it. So why is R looking for tcltk in /opt/X11/lib and how can I point it to the correct location?
Possibly relevant system details...
M2 MacBook Pro, MacOS Sonoma 14.4.1
R.version 4.3.3

Linux user here, but I think this is similar. Try checking your ~/.bash_profile or ~/.zshrc for related entries and edit the path, or add line export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=opt/R/arm64:$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH at the end and then source ~/.zshrc.

@jay.sf I was thinking it might be a path issue, but this didn't work so maybe it's looking at a different path variable?

Just asked the r-sig-mac mailing list for help. If I get an answer there, I'll post it here.
